# How to make ltrace -S show all arguments of system calls?

Tags: ltrace

I was [using `ltrace -S` to see what system calls `dlopen` was making](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/226524/what-system-call-is-used-to-load-libraries-in-linux/462710#462710) but then I noticed that `SYS_mmap` was limited to only 4 arguments:

```
SYS_mmap(0x7f1c325fe000, 8192, 3, 2066)
```

while it [takes a total of 6 arguments](https://github.com/torvalds/linux/blob/v4.18/mm/mmap.c#L1592). In particular, the file descriptor, which is the sixth argument is not shown, which is crucial for my analysis.

Is there a way to make `ltrace` show all my arguments?

Tested in `ltrace` 0.7.3, Ubuntu 16.04.

Comment: The line for mmap is commented out in `/etc/ltrace.conf` in version 0.7.3. `;addr SYS_mmap(addr,ulong,int,int,int,long)`. I don't know why.  Maybe because the system call on Linux differs slightly from the glibc wrapper. If you want, copy ltrace.conf to another file, remove the `;`, and give ltrace the `-F /path/to/new/ltrace.conf` option.

Comment: @MarkPlotnick thanks for your UNIX-fu.

Answer (score 0):

As [mentioned by Mark Plotnick](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51861263/how-to-make-ltrace-s-show-all-arguments-of-system-calls?noredirect=1#comment93009423_51861263):

```
sed 's/;addr SYS_mmap/addr SYS_mmap'/ /etc/ltrace.conf > ltrace.conf
ltrace -S -F ltrace.conf ./dlopen.out
```

and now the `mmap`s look just right:

```
SYS_mmap(0, 285983, 1, 2, 3, 0) = 0x7f7db3ea6000
```

Tested on Ubuntu 18.04, ltrace 0.7.3.